# D8: Replacing Contact Form Title With Label

Tags: theming, 8, emails

I've searched around for this answer but to no avail.

All I want to do is with any contact form I create I want to replace its default title (usually "contact") with the form's label.

So instead of {{ title }} something like {{page.label}}.

I need more descriptive titles for my forms.

Answer (score 0):

`{{ page['#title'] }}` seems to work consistently and accesses the form's label.